# How to get HTML formatting to work with multiple emails using JavaMail

Tags: java, html, gmail, jakarta-mail

I'm trying to send multiple emails that use HTML for formatting, but only the first email gets sent as HTML, the rest are sent as plain text.

Anyone know what the problem could be?

Here's my code for sending the multiple emails:

```java
public static int sendEmail(int ind) throws AddressException, MessagingException, InterruptedException, IOException {
    mailServerProperties = System.getProperties();
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.port", "587");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
    mailServerProperties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
    getMailSession = Session.getDefaultInstance(mailServerProperties, null);
    generateMailMessage = new MimeMessage(getMailSession);
    generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings");
    Transport transport = getMailSession.getTransport("smtp");
    transport.connect("smtp.gmail.com", email, password);
    Person perp;
    for(int i = ind; i < people.size(); i++){
        perp = people.get(i);
        generateMailMessage.setRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(perp.email));
        emailBody = "Dear " + perp.name + ", <br><br> Testing. <br><br>The Tester";
        generateMailMessage.setContent(emailBody, "text/html; charset=utf-8");
        generateMailMessage.setSubject("Greetings"+i);
        try{
            transport.sendMessage(generateMailMessage, generateMailMessage.getAllRecipients());
            System.out.println(i);

        } catch(Exception SMTPSendFailedException) {
            System.out.println("Number "+i+" failed");
            ind = i;
            break;
        }
        ind = i;
    }
    System.out.println("round done");
    transport.close();
    return ind;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/JXyTBFFX

Comment: Edit your question and include the code in your question.  External links tend to go away over time, which would make your question useless to future readers.

Comment: What does the [JavaMail debug output](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#debug) show?  Also, you'll want to [change Session.getDefaultInstance to Session.getInstance](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#commonmistakes).